How to convert nuxt props from typescript in to js
I was wondering how can I convert this little snippet from typescript into JS.
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { type Content } from '@prismicio/client';

  defineProps(
    getSliceComponentProps<Content.HeroSlice>([
      "slice",
    ]),
  );
</script>


Remove the TypeScript-specific syntax lang="ts" attribute from the script tag

Sure yes. But how do i re write the code?

I'm not familiar with the package you are using but I think it will work something like this. ``````

This should be working well
<script setup>
import * as prismic from '@prismicio/client'

defineProps(getSliceComponentProps(["slice"]))
</script>

More info can be found in the docs.
Since you're not typing it, you don't even need the Content in the TS generic.
Use prismic.[your method] to do your usual Prismic stuff.

I think it worked and you need to use type in import because  using typescript :
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { type Content } from '@prismicio/client';

  defineProps(
    getSliceComponentProps<Content.HeroSlice>([
      "slice",
    ]),
  );
</script>


TypeScript uses types and interfaces, that are not recognized by JavaScript. So remove all the type declarations, and keep the imports, because modern JavaScript (ES6) supports imports.
<script setup>
  import { Content } from '@prismicio/client';
  const props = getSliceComponentProps(["slice"]);
</script>

